# Do we need IT-specific tags?

Tags: discussion, tags

Today I looked at our tags page and saw a number of tags, which are not specific to linguistics, but rather describe some IT fields or software titles like:

- excel
- cell
- spreadsheet
- datasets
- nlp
- ner
- named-entity-recognition

Do we really need to create tags for all this software-related questions? I propose mark them all with generic `software` tag.

And maybe another one may be needed for software localization questions (like all those drupal questions).

What do you think?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Burn it with fire. :)**

Indeed, why *could* we need it? I can't imagine a visitor to Ukrainian Language.SE who actually searches for tags like [drupal](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/drupal) or, God forbid, [mysql-real-escape-string](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mysql-real-escape-string) ([proof](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/97182/when-are-question-tags-irrelevant-and-should-be-removed)). Seriously, it would be equivalent to searching for this very question by tag [create](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/create) or [mark](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mark).

Tags should tell what the question **is about**, not just what it **contains**.

[terminology](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/terminology) is just fine; [software](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/software) — maybe, but I would say it's too soon to tell for sure.

Comment: I find field names useful in vocabulary questions. So there should be a tag like [tag:computers] or [tag:information-technology] (whatever makes sense from an Ukrainian perspective — on [french.se] we use “informatique” which is the French word for both “computer science” and “IT”).

Comment: @Gilles yes, but we should have limit somewhere. Otherwise, those who are interested about [tennis](http://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/79/) would demand their own tag. And, in the end of the day, we would end up with an infinite number of tags that cover 5 questions each. Yes, *drupal* may have 10. :-) If we see abundance of such questions, we will branch out a specific tag. But right now, the hierarchy of tags: `terminology → sports → tennis → tennis-strokes → kurnikova-style` is only at its first stage, `terminology`. :-) Does it make sense?

Comment: There's no tag hierarchy. So just stick at level 1. [tag:terminology] is too broad to be really useful. [tag:sport] is level 1.

Comment: @Gilles hmm, what do you then suggest to do with `chemistry`, `nuclear-physics`, and hundreds of similar areas of interest, you name it?

Comment: @Gilles also, English Language Learners has neither `sports` nor `chemistry` (haven't checked everything); Chinese.SE has [sport](http://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sport), 2 questions, and no `tennis`. We don't know the future, however; perhaps UL.SE will have hundreds Q's for `sports` or `i.t.`, unlike the sites above.